# Change rpi appearance and theme settings through command line

Tags: pi-4, terminal, lxde

Is there a way to change the appearance and theme settings of the rpi through the command line or by editing a file? I do not want to use the UI options that you can access through the rpi desktop. Ideally, I want a series of commands I can run in a .sh file (or a file I can programmatically edit) so when I'm formatting a new SD card I can automatically set the theme/appearance without having to click around to make changes manually.

Some changes I would like to make include making the desktop menu bar autohide, removing wastebasket from the desktop, changing the theme background and foreground colors, etc.

Comment: Gut feel is that you are going to have to re-create these by going through the source https://github.com/RPi-Distro and working out what they do :-(  It may be simpler to config a clean box and clone it or try to pull the X11 config files off.

Comment: Please don't answer your question within the question. Please create an answer. You can just cut it from the question and paste into an answer. Then after two days mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

The questioner answered his question within the question. Here is it to have a correct answer.

> As suggested, I ended up going through rpi files until I found the config files I was looking for. For reference `/.config/` directory includes all the appearance-related files where `/.config/lxsession` gives you access to the colors and themes for the system and `/.config/lxpanel` gives you access to the desktop menu bar. In those directories I edited the relevant `.config` files.